# html element rendering is not getting done perfectly when using display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want to demonstrate the problem with a situation.
Here, I had written a markup like below

```
<header>this is header-position is fixed</header>
<section id="one">
  <aside>why just a simple text taking me down!?</aside><!--
  --><section id="sub"></section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Now I had built a css styling for above elements as below.

```
*,*:after,*:before {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:100%;
}

#one {
  margin-top:100px;
  border:1px solid #0f0;
  width:100%;
}

aside {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #00f;
  width:20%;
  height:200px;
}

#sub {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  height:200px;
  width:80%;
}
```

*Problem is that, the elements are not generating as expected.*

*Main problem is with `<aside>` & `<section>` tags that are next to each other.*

**Present styling is giving problem in rendering the `<aside>` element**

Please check the below link
http://codepen.io/Yeswanth-JG/pen/mpwzL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Inline-block` items require vertical alignment as their default is `baseline`

Add this:

```
aside {
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sub {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Adjusted Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Jmrnl)

[**What is Vertical Align @ CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

Comment: I prefer adding vertical-align to these elements parent (section > * {vertical-align:top;}), so if there are more elements in future, you won't need to write additional styles

Comment: Paul & @Veselin
Thanks for the valuable information.!

Comment: If I present any info in section, It will change the layout..(just figured out the issue, after questioning!)
http://codepen.io/Yeswanth-JG/pen/BHfkj (without vertical-align declaration..!)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:left` to the aside and it will be fixed.

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/Bhcds)

Comment: Thanks buddy..!
But, actually want the help using only "display" property.

Sorry for this. I had not mentioned.!